# How i know when a web site is using RDF?

Tags: search-engine, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

How do I know when a web site uses an RDF ?

For example , I know that eBay and Amazon uses RDF because I've read in many articles, but as I know it in practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, there is currently no single standardized way for websites to "advertise" their use of RDF. You find out by them informing you about it in some fashion, e.g. by them publishing a link to API documentation that describes how they use RDF, or indeed by writing an article about it, so pretty much the same way you find out about any REST API / web service. Of course, in the case of RDF/linked data you are often helped by the fact that other datasets you already know about may be linking to the new source, thus making it discoverable.

There are some attempts at defining more standardized mechanisms for 'advertising' a website's linked data use. The [W3C VoID specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/) is the closest thing to a standard in that regard: it provides a vocabulary for publishers to describe the data and access mechanisms they offer, and it also gives pointers on how to make things discoverable. Unfortunately, it is not (yet) very widely adopted.